# How to prevent creation of "System Volume Information" folder in Windows 10 for USB flash drives?

Tags: windows-10, usb

Whenever I plug in a USB flash drive, Windows 10 insists on creating the folder "System Volume Information." I really don't need this for a USB flash drive, especially if I'm planning on using this in my car's sound system, which is organized by artist as each folder's name.  If I Google the title of this question, I get several hits, most of which are nearly identical to the one on [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-system-volume-information-folder-usb). In Windows 10 AU this doesn't work, as another step is necessary, though it's my understanding it does in Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1. I'm unable to verify first hand.

Comment: It stores your restore points, and you can eliminate it if you delete all of them and turn off system protection.  But if you do that you had better have a good backup system of your own in place.

Comment: @SDsolar, you're absolutely correct; system restore points are stored in the System Volume Information folder, but there's no reason to have one on a USB thumb drive.

Comment: System restore is controlled individually by drive letter.  So if you don't want them on your thumb drive go into the system protection menu, delete them then shut it off for that drive.

Comment: I have done that, and while it does prevent creation of system restore points for the drive in question, it does not prevent creation of the System Volume Information folder, which contains many other objects besides system restore points (e.g. WPSetings.dat).

Comment: Same results here.  It is disabled yet there are a bunch of files in there.  With an administrator CMD I can use rmdir /r/s "system volume information" but I want it not to come back.  And as for Windows Club, Adblock is telling me it is blocking 15 items, and the page pops up like Forbes.com to prevent me from seeing it.  No way will I whitelist it with that many trackers.

Answer (score 18):

I really wanted to get this solution in one place so that anyone else looking for it can find it.

From [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-system-volume-information-folder-usb):

> Step 1:

Using GPEDIT to modify **Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries** setting:

In Windows 10 / 8.1 Pro & Enterprise Editions, press **Windows Key + R** combination, type put **gpedit.msc** in **Run** dialog box and hit Enter to open the **Local Group Policy Editor**.

Navigate here: **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Search**

In the right pane, look for the setting named **Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries** and double click it.

Click on **Enabled** and then click **Apply** followed by **OK**. Close the *Local Group Policy Editor*.

If you cannot change this setting via gpedit.msc, then you'll need to make the change in the registry. If you are not comfortable doing so, please do not attempt. Open regedit from Run. Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows**. Locate the key **DisableRemovableDriveIndexing**. If it does not exit, create it by right clicking the right pane, select **New > Key** and make the key a **DWORD Value**. Double click on the key (or right click and select Modify) and change the value to 1 and select Ok.
**Step 2:**
For Windows 10 this additional step is necessary. Go back to **Run**, type **services.msc**, click OK. In the right pane scroll down to **Windows Search**, double click it and in **Startup type:** select **Disabled**. Click **OK** and then close. Just to be safe reboot.
I have done the above and now whenever I insert a USB flash drive, Windows does not create a "System Volume Information" folder. However, it does create this folder for USB hard drives, which is exactly what I wanted. As far as I can tell Windows search still works, but I do not know how this setting affects Cortana, as I do not use it (don't even have a microphone). I tried to find the website where I originally found the second part of this but can't seem to. It doesn't come up again on a Google search.
It's been my experience with Windows that what works on one person's machine may not on another's. Putting your machine back the way it was should not be difficult. And there's always the possibility that you may have a Local Policy setting that prevents these changes.
This solution does work in Creators Update. The problem I experienced was due to the loss of my c:\users > d:\users junction that I lost during the Creators Update installation. Once I reestablished it, Windows stopped creating the "System Volume Information" folder upon inserting a USB flash drive. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's incorrect registry path. One more key level "Windows Search" should be there actually containing DisableRemovableDriveIndexing value (NB: the latter is a value, not a key, don't mix up these two concepts!)

Comment: Does not work, with either configuration. Folder keeps getting created by windows.

Comment: ok, there is only one file that keeps being created: tracking.log (i wonder what it is and how can i prevent this file from being created)

Comment: FOUND the culprit! It was the "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" service! Disabled now, and no SVI folder getting created.

Comment: IIUC, this is not a solution. If you disable Windows Search service then the search still works. But new/changed content is not indexed, on all drives. Which is not what most users want

Comment: Disabling both Indexer and DTC services is **NOT A SOLUTION!** The indexer updates the database of start menu shortcuts; without it, hitting Win and typing a name of the program will yield no (new) results. DTC is part of COM+; neither is used for what they were made: DCOM was more of a disaster than a useful cross-machine RPC for COM. But both DTC and COM+ are critical for Windows Runtime. Disabling DTC may break UWP Apps and other RT clients. Most processes with "Broker" in their name will degrade. I'm trying to solve same issue, but boy, could I have only thought of a worse solution!

Answer (score 10):

Bill Oertell's solution is missing one crucial step; at least this step is necessary with the latest version of Windows 10. I'm adding that step here, so that there is a permanent record of the full solution.

You should do everything he advises, but in addition, while you are in services.msc disabling "Windows Search" you also need to disable "Storage Service", by using the exact same sequence of steps.

Don't worry, despite its name it isn't a necessary service. At least I've not experienced any ill effects for disabling it.

To verify that this is the culprit, you can do the following. Leave the service running, then start Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) utility. When the "Filters" dialog opens, add a filter with the following settings:

"Path" "Contains" "system volume information"

After you click <kbd>OK</kbd>, the main window shows. Pull down the "Filter" menu, and ensure "Drop Filtered Events" is checked.

Then insert a USB flash drive.

You should see some lines appearing in the main window. You'll see the path referring to S.V.I. on the USB drive. The ones you care about have a Process Name of svchost.exe.

Note down the PID from the next column, and then start Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) tool. Click on the PID column to sort by ascending PID, and then scroll down to find the entry with the value you noted just above.

Hover over the name of the process and you'll see the service(s) run by this process. It should show "Storage Service."

You have just found your smoking gun.

Comment: thanks for posting this. This solution was posted just yesterday on Microsoft Community by another user, whose name I haven't received permission to use here. I've tested it on my machine (Windows 10 Build 1709), and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @BillOertell That might well have been me. :)  If the tone of the message seemed somewhat critical of Microsoft, and the initials of the poster match the first two letters of my user name then it probably was.  What is interesting is that the thread where I posted is no longer showing up in Google searches, at least I'm totally unable to find it.

Comment: I didn't really take a good look at your SE user ID. That was most definitely you. Thanks again.

Comment: Apparently turning off "Storage Service" disables the Microsoft Store app. With this off I was getting error code: 0x800706D9.  The article here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/windows-10-store-is-giving-me-this-error-code/eb00ca76-8d7d-4db0-b27a-897f6289683e lists this service as one cause for the Microsoft Store app error. I was receiving this when I tried to install a couple of apps from the Store. Turning it back on fixed it. If you use this and then find MS Store apps not installing, turn it back on.

Comment: @BillOertell  Ugh.  Typical of Microsoft.  It's a complete non-issue for me since I don't use the Microsoft Store at all, but I guess it means if you do need access to the store you're stuck.  Regretfully, complaining to Microsoft about this is about as effective as trying to stop an Amtrak train by yelling at it.  They are so fixated on the party line that S.V.I. is an essential folder and you can't live without it, that they simply can't grasp what's going on.  Kinda like trying to explain color to a blind person. :(

Comment: this one did the trick for me

Comment: God, NO! Disabling StorSvc breaks delivery of both new apps and other content from Store and updates to already installed apps. It's a huge breakage of the OS and a **security vulnerability,** as it leaves you with dismaintained old apps.

Comment: @kkm That depends on your opinion.  I have no use for any of the MS store apps, so updates for them are a complete non-issue, since I don't have any installed in the first place.  Don't forget that while I do admit this prohibits updates to store apps, it **also** prohibits installing them in the first place.  Something I personally consider a benefit rather than a liability.  That said, Windows update still works fine for OS security patches, so I'm not crystal clear exactly where there might be a problem.

Comment: Of course, you can break your system any way you wish. Your system does have apps and bundles that depend on RT, even though they are not listed. My _opinion_ is that making your system unstable and vulnerable will not make you happy in the long run. Your _opinion_ is that fighting more and more glitches overt time as some parts of your system are updated and others aren't is a cool way to kill spare time. The best we can do is agree to disagree.

Comment: @kkm You'd have a case if my system actually exhibited any sort of instability.  However, I've been running systems like this since the early days of Windows 10, with **no problems whatsoever**.  In my case it was a *necessity* to kill the creation of S.V.I. on flash drives, since doing so caused the flash in my first ever CPAP to be unreadable.  Apparently the CPAP had fairly brain-dead FAT32 firmware.  It considered any filename that wasn't 8.3 as drive corruption, forcing me to reformat the flash every time I uploaded data to my doctor.  Tell me this is desirable, I dare you.

Comment: Yeah, S.V.I. is an ugly thing.

Comment: ...and I just found it on my Hyper-V Linux server ESP partition(!!!). Empty. All I did was drop the UEFI shell .efi file onto this VHD from Windows. As soon as the drive is mounted, the thing is created. Ugh!

Answer (score 3):

Although the following is not a clean solution, it could be a workaround in some cases.

In my case  I didn't want anything to be written on the drive. The creation of the folder ***System Volume Information*** was causing me issues.

Because none of the solutions seemed to work for Windows 10 v1703, what I did and seems to be working is this:

1. Delete contents of ***System Volume Information*** folder
2. Delete the folder itself
3. Create a new **file** with name ***System Volume Information***

For #1 and #2 I used the command in elevated command prompt:

```
del /S /Q "Q:\System Volume Information" && rmdir "Q:\System Volume Information"
```

For #3 I used the command

```
fsutil file createnew "Q:\System Volume Information" 0
```

**You need to replace Q: with your drive letter.**

Since we can't have a folder and a file with the same name, the System Volume Information folder can't be created.

**Note**: My drive is FAT formatted. For NTFS formatted drives, I guess we need to first take ownership of the folder before deleting it.

Comment: May be that's also replaced by a blank symlink to `nul` with `mklink` command.

Comment: I'm using USB Flash drives to shuttle files between a Linux machine and a Windows 11 machine.  To implement this solution I create the empty "System Volume Information" file with the USB drive mounted on the Linux system, using the "touch" command, and then assign read-only permissions with "chmod 444".  Having to place the file on the drive beforehand is a minor annoyance compared to Windows indiscriminately "fixing" it.

Comment: make the file hidden: `fsutil file createnew "Q:\System Volume Information" 0 && attrib +s +h "Q:\System Volume Information"`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows 7. In my case the folder appeared only on one USB stick, so I was convinced the problem wasn't about indexing or restoration being configured wrongly for removable devices. I didn't attempt to perform the configuration changes suggested in other answers.

The problem was fixed by deleting the folder. Of course the folder is protected (read only, system attribute and hidden), so the attributes need to be reset first.

Open `cmd.exe` with administrator rights ([instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/)).

Set the default volume to your USB drive (e: in my case). This removes the need to type full paths:
`C:\Windows\System32> e:`
`E:>`

Reset attributes on folder and content using [attrib](https://www.computerhope.com/attribhl.htm):
`E:>attrib -h -s -r "System Volume Information" /S /D`

(after this command the folder must be visible.)

Delete directory:
`E:>rd "System Volume Information"`

Unplug the USB stick (after [using "eject" if necessary](https://www.howtogeek.com/118546/htg-explains-do-you-really-need-to-safely-remove-usb-sticks/)). Now if you plug it again the folder won't reappear (unless removable media have been configured as indexed. In that case the other answers can be used).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have just solved 2 problems, which is that in many cases you need Windows Search running (so you can use the Windows Media Player Service) and also want to keep S.V.I. folders off removable drives:

[how to both enable Windows Search AND avoid System Volume Information folder being written to removable drives](https://superuser.com/questions/1725504/how-to-both-enable-windows-search-and-avoid-system-volume-information-folder-bei/1725506#1725506)

I'm a bit shocked I figured it out as fast as I did but involves 2 more GPEDIT settings in the same Search section as the first one.  Please verify independently if you can.

Added a day later...this is still working for me today.