# how to both enable Windows Search AND avoid System Volume Information folder being written to removable drives

Tags: windows-search, windows-media-player, removable-media, gpedit, exclude

This refers to Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 20H2 and probably all Windows 10 versions.

I need to have Windows Media Player Service running on my machine so that media devices can access it to play videos.

**WMPS must have Windows Search as as prerequisite**, unfortunately.

I've seen all the solutions for keeping S.V.I. folders off removable drives, but **they always involve disabling the Windows Search Service**.

Solutions I've seen always involve enabling "Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries" in GPEDIT, disabling Storage Service, and disabling the needed Windows Search.

How can it be possible to accomplish this without disabling Windows Search?

Note: I shortened and formatted this version a day after first published.

Comment: Can you edit, use some formatting, and perhaps change how the question is laid out so it's more clear?

Comment: I'll clarify here.  Simply this.  I wanted to be able to avoid the S.V.I. folders on my USB flash drives while at the same time being able to use Windows Media Player Service, which requires the Windows Search Service that other solutions require to be disabled if you want S.V.I. folders to not be created on your removable (USB flash) drives.  My solution below works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.  Please test yourself and verify.

I have Windows Search running.  I never disabled it.

Storage Service is disabled as before.

The difference being I enabled two more settings in GPEDIT in the same location as the first setting mentioned (Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search).

Enable as before: "Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries"

Enable these two ADDITIONAL settings:
"Default excluded paths" AND "Prevent indexing certain paths".
In each of those two, specify the drive letters to exclude (i.e. "F:\")

(Since I enabled both of the two additional settings at the same time, I don't know if one of them may not be needed but at least one is.)

Plugged in my USB drive with SVI folder already removed. It does not show up anymore.

Caveat...the only drawback in this solution is that you must specify any drive letters that removable drives can be assigned by Windows, whereas the solution involving disabling Windows Search doesn't require that.

Added a day later...this continue to work today.  I setup F:, G:\ and H:\ which are drive letters used if I plug in as many as 3 USB flash drives.

Comment: Someone down-voted this without trying it or explaining why.  It just works a little different than the solution that involves disabling Windows Search...which causes WMPS not to work anymore.  It's a very worthy alternative.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I can explain. Disabling StorSvc is a security vulnerability, as you can no longer get new apps from Store, and more importantly, receive updates to the installed apps. Dismainained apps is a vulnerability. Some apps or bundles are hidden, can be uninstalled only from command line, and they are _still_ updated through Store. Do not disable StorSvc.

Comment: I see no evidence that it's a particularly onerous security vulnerability. Source for that? On the other hand, I tend to eschew all Microsoft Store apps. Without disabling that, you can't keep SVI off your flash drives. I feel it's more for fixed storage.